# Telegram Bot API - AnswerCallbackQuery

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

1- How can I send the user to  visit a url ( a Telegram Channel or a website) from AnswerCallbackQuery? 
There a url parameter but it respondes URL_Invalid for any url I pass though!

2- For Inline keyboard if I pass a url, AnswerCallbackQuery won't be call anymore! Is there any way to call AnswerCallbackQuery method to catch the user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your 2nd question. For the first question if you can paste part of your code for sending replies then I can take a look.

To catch which url the user clicks, one way is to create something like a url shortener in your server, and then redirect the user to the final url. 
For example let's say you want the user to go to example.com/something. Instead of that, create a url like this: yourserver.com/A_random_URL_mapped_to_USER. 
Once the user visits this url, then you will catch which url they clicked on, and then your server will redirect them to their final url.